# Why header allow cross domain does not allow use echo to print the variable value?

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a angular file, it does a post request sending variables (email,user, keysuser) to php file to send an email. But when I use echo to print the values the response is an error. Let me show you:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$dataJsonDecode  = json_decode($data);
$email = $dataJsonDecode->email;
$username = $dataJsonDecode->username;
$id = $dataJsonDecode->keyuser;
$subject = "Welcome";
$message="Hi".echo $username ." welcome to the site... blabla";
$header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'From: GoVir <govir@example.com>' . "\r\n";

if(mail($email,$subject,$message,$header)){
 echo 'success';
}else{
echo 'Error';
}
?>
```

And this the error

- MLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.govircarpool.com/correo/correo.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.*

It works and send the email well when I send only string or html but when use echo to concatenate the value these error happend.

Comment: Are you talking about line `$message="Hi".echo $username ." welcome to the site... blabla";`? the `echo` shouldn't be there: `$message="Hi" .$username ." welcome to the site... blabla"`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove echo used before $message

```
$message="Hi".$username ." welcome to the site... blabla";
```

and check whether your mail function is return true or not. If mail function does not return true then you will always get "Error".